# Spring security 5/spring boot 2.2: No AuthenticationProvider found for org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

We are upgrading our apps from spring boot 1.5.x to 2.2.x and spring security 4.x to 5.3.2. We have the following defined for our web security:

```
 @EnableWebSecurity
 @Configuration
 @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
 @Profile("uno")
 public class UnoSecurityConfig extends AbstractSecurityConfig {

 @Autowired
 private ServletContext servletContext;

 @Override
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    BasicAuthFilter basicAuthFilter = new BasicAuthFilter();
    basicAuthFilter.init(new BasicAuthSSOFilterConfig(servletContext));
    http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/ping").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/ping").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/**").hasAuthority(OurPrivileges.ALL_MEASURE)
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()//allow CORS option calls
            .and()
            .addFilter(securityContextPersistenceFilter())
            .addFilterAfter(new RequestContextFilter(), SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.class)
            .addFilterAfter(new CrossFramePreventionFilter(), RequestContextFilter.class)
            .addFilterAfter(basicAuthFilter, CrossFramePreventionFilter.class)
            .addFilterAfter(preAuthenticationFilter(), BasicAuthFilter.class)
            .addFilterAfter(exceptionTranslationFilter(), PreAuthenticatedUserDetailsFilter.class);
    http.headers().contentSecurityPolicy(SecurityUtility.getContentSecurityPolicy());
}
```

When I try to hit the /ping endpoint it should just let me in but instead i get the authentication box pop up and then denied.  I see this in the logs:

```
2020-05-26 09:56:39.881-0500 DEBUG APP=829 COMP=782 [https-jsse-nio-30062-exec- 
2:OrRequestMatcher:[]] -Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/actuator/health/**']
2020-05-26 09:56:39.881-0500 DEBUG APP=829 COMP=782 [https-jsse-nio-30062-exec- 
2:AntPathRequestMatcher:[]] -Checking match of request : '/ping'; against '/actuator/health/**'
2020-05-26 09:56:39.881-0500 DEBUG APP=829 COMP=782 [https-jsse-nio-30062-exec-2:OrRequestMatcher:[]] -Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/actuator/info/**']
2020-05-26 09:56:39.881-0500 DEBUG APP=829 COMP=782 [https-jsse-nio-30062-exec-2:AntPathRequestMatcher:[]] -Checking match of request : '/ping'; against '/actuator/info/**'
2020-05-26 09:56:39.881-0500 DEBUG APP=829 COMP=782 [https-jsse-nio-30062-exec-2:OrRequestMatcher:[]] -Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/actuator']
2020-05-26 09:56:39.881-0500 DEBUG APP=829 COMP=782 [https-jsse-nio-30062-exec-2:AntPathRequestMatcher:[]] -Checking match of request : '/ping'; against '/actuator'
2020-05-26 09:56:39.881-0500 DEBUG APP=829 COMP=782 [https-jsse-nio-30062-exec-2:OrRequestMatcher:[]] -Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/actuator/']
2020-05-26 09:56:39.881-0500 DEBUG APP=829 COMP=782 [https-jsse-nio-30062-exec-2:AntPathRequestMatcher:[]] -Checking match of request : '/ping'; against '/actuator/'
2020-05-26 09:56:39.881-0500 DEBUG APP=829 COMP=782 [https-jsse-nio-30062-exec-2:OrRequestMatcher:[]] -No matches found
2020-05-26 09:56:39.881-0500 DEBUG APP=829 COMP=782 [https-jsse-nio-30062-exec-2:AntPathRequestMatcher:[]] -Request '/ping' matched by universal pattern '/**'
```

Other endpoints that require authentication dont let me in and give 401/403 errors with exception thrown being the title of the post.  It seems clear that spring isnt using our custom logic.  None of our code changed, just the dependencies.  How do I get beyond this?

Answer (score 0):

The configure override creates a new filter chain and it goes behind the default springSecurityFilterChain in precedence and therefore accepts all requests and denies everything.  I added @Order(1) to my security config class which resolved the problem.